# Devexpress - Set editor's "isValid" through Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I'm using `custom validation`for fields in DevExpress and I need to set if a field is valid or not in my Javascript function.

I'm able to get `isValid` attribute:

```
$('#form').dxForm('instance').getEditor('appID').option('isValid')
```

But I don't know how to set it.

Comment: I think you should use it like this  **$('#form').dxForm('instance').getEditor('appID').isValid()**

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dxForm(...).getEditor(...).isValid is not a function"

Comment: Please try **$('#form').dxForm('instance').getEditor('appID').isValid** it will return either true or false

Comment: Try `getEditor('appID').option("isValid", true)`. Are you want to set validation manually with that?

Comment: @fizakhan Nope, is `undefined`. I can check `isValid` attribute as I said in post, but I can't change it.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto that seems to work! Gonna make some tests, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [DevExtreme documentation about `dxForm`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_1/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxForm/Methods/#getEditorfield), `option()` function has overload which contains 2 arguments:

> `option(optionName, optionValue)`
>
> Sets a value to the specified configuration option of this component.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - optionName: String The name of the required option.
> - optionValue: any The value you wish to assign to the required option.

Therefore, you can set `isValid` validation option with this line:

```
$('#form').dxForm('instance').getEditor('appID').option('isValid', true);
```

Related usage:

[dxForm - FormData update is triggering dxValidatiors on load](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T562241/dxform-formdata-update-is-triggering-dxvalidatiors-on-load)